# Memory Leaks while using gstbuffer

Tags: memory-leaks, gstreamer, free

I have a pipeline, which takes data from webcam and process it.

For the processing i need to pull that buffer to **appsink** and push it into pipeline by using **appsrc** element.

While pushing i had used **gst_buffer_new_wrapped** function.

Then a new buffer is allocated every time i am pushing the data. But how to free that memory is the problem.

I had tried gst_buffer_unref(buffer);

Then got below error.

```
 Error in `./uuHiesSoaServer': free(): invalid pointer: 0x00007fddf52f6000
```

I had take the data into an unsigned char pointer and then wrapped into a gstbuffer based on the size.

Now how to free the allocated memory?

```
g_signal_emit_by_name (Source, "push-buffer", Buffer, &ret);
```

I had used above function for pushing data into Source(appsrc).

That function will continuously call on a separate thread.

When data available to it, then the thread function will create a buffer using

```
gst_buffer_new_wrapped((void *)data, Size);
```

When checking in valgrind, for memory leaks, above line was shown as a leak.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How do you push the buffer into appsrc?

If you use gst_app_src_push_buffer function I guess you do not have to free resources because [gst_app_src_push_buffer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsrc.html#gst-app-src-push-buffer) will own the buffer (which means it also frees it)
Check [this example](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/tests/examples/app/appsrc_ex.c)

If you use need-data callback you may need to free data - check [this example](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base/tree/tests/examples/app/appsrc-stream.c)

HTH

Comment: @PrasanthKumarArisetti  have you checked the second example about need-data in my answer?  they are using exactly the same method as you ;)

Comment: @PrasanthKumarArisetti: while using GStreamer I found out that its always good to check for examples inside source code of gst, sometimes there arent examples and sometimes there are - you never know until you check .. this one was in tests/examples/app/ directory of source for gst-plugins-base .. you can always browse through sources at [cgit](https://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/)